# javascript d3 line graph with ordinal x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I am new to d3, I am trying to draw a map with ordinal x axis, e.g. for this data

```
{cat: 10, dog: 3, pig: 7, bird: 7}
```

I want to show cat, dog, pig, bird on x axis and the corresponding numbers on y axis.

I am trying to use `d3.line()` function, but a bit confused what to send for `x` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your data structure to something like this:

```
var data = [{
    name: "cat",
    value: 10
}, {
    name: "dog",
    value: 3
}, {
    name: "pig",
    value: 7
}, {
    name: "bird",
    value: 7
}];
```

That way, you can define the line generator (look at the demo to see what those scales are):

```
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.name)
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value)
    });
```

Thus, the `x` argument is the qualitative value of the `name` variable, while the `y` is the quantitative value of the `value` variable.

The important point here is: if you're using a qualitative variable for the x axis, set a qualitative scale for dealing with that qualitative variable, and pass the return of such scale to the line generator.

Here is the demo:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "cat",
    value: 10
}, {
    name: "dog",
    value: 3
}, {
    name: "pig",
    value: 7
}, {
    name: "bird",
    value: 7
}];

var width = 500,
    height = 200;

var svg = d3.selectAll("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) {
        return d.name
    }))
    .range([50, width - 50])
    .padding(0.5);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
        return d.value
    }) * 1.1])
    .range([height - 50, 10]);

var line = d3.line()
 .x(function(d){ return xScale(d.name)})
 .y(function(d){ return yScale(d.value)});
 
svg.append("path")
 .attr("d", line(data))
 .attr("stroke", "teal")
 .attr("stroke-width", "2")
 .attr("fill", "none");

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,150)")
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50,0)")
    .attr("class", "yAxis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```